# Deleting value="Comment?" as soon as it is clicked from the input box

Tags: php, javascript, html

I created an input box and says "comments?" before the user enters anything in it.Code;

```
          <input type="text" name="saysome" value = "comments?"/>
```

But, i want to delete this "comments?" as soon as it is clicked.I am trying to do input box just like the search box in here, actually exaclty same. How can i do that?Can it be done by only javascipt? :(

Thanks

Comment: Try `placeholder=""` instead of `value=` and a [JS fallback](https://github.com/parndt/jquery-html5-placeholder-shim) for older browsers.

Comment: Not sure PHP applies to anything here

Answer (score 3):

You can use the html5 placeholder attribute found here:
[HTML5 Specs](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-placeholder-attribute)

For example:

```
 <input type="text" name="saysome" placeholder = "comments?"/>
```

You could also take a javascript approach for browsers that do not support HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

Simple method that will clear it anytime the box has focus, and not if the user has entered anything into it

```
<input type="text" name="TB" value="Please Enter.." onfocus="this.value==this.defaultValue?this.value='':null"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-jquery:

```
onClick="clearComments()"

function clearComments() {
    commentInput = document.getElementById("commentsId");
    if(commentInput.value == 'comments?') {
       commentInput.value = '';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As other commenters mentioned, you should check out placeholder. To answer your question though, this method will remove the text on mouse click if the user has not already entered something. This assumes that the id of the input is `textbox`. You will have to change it to whatever you have or else assign the input an id.

```
<input id="textbox" type="text"/>
```

and the JS:

```
document.getElementById('textbox').onclick = function()
{
    var box = document.getElementById('textbox');
    if(box.value==box.defaulValue)box.value =='';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="saysome" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='comments?';" onclick="this.value=''" value="comments?" />
```

**See this example @ http://x.co/Z2pa**

Answer (score -1):

Without jQuery:

Give the input an ID, and clear its value using an onclick event.

```
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="test" onclick="if(document.getElementById('test').value=='test')document.getElementById('test').value='';">
```

Also supports older browsers that don't use HTML 5.

Comment: -1, this will clear it every time, not just the first time when the text says "comments?"

Comment: Good catch. Fixed it, tentatively. Better is to get a separate variable to keep it from happening more than once...